# What's the purpose of stating public encapsulation for PHP OOP?

Tags: php, oop, public

I'm dipping my toe into PHP's object-oriented side and I've been wondering about public encapsulation. I understand the purpose of private and protected encapsulation, but when it comes to public, why state it?

So for example, I have
`public $name;`

But if I can just set `$this->name = 'whatever'`, then whycome `"public $varname"` exists?

Comment: BTW, that's not really *encapsulation*.

Comment: Encapsulation means you're encapsulating the inner workings and state of a class and only provide an unchanging interface to the user of the class. *"Public encapsulation*" is something of an oxymoron, at least the way you used it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's always better to explicitly specify the properties of a class. Yes, you could just set them dynamically in a method when needed, but it makes it that much harder when you're trying to remember whether it was supposed to be `$varname`, `$var_name`, `$varName` or whether you have already "declared" the property at all.

It also makes sure the property exists when you're trying to work with it, which saves you calls to `isset` and makes your code more concise and robust.